# how to validate rest api postdata in codeignitor 4 and how to add custom error message in $validation->check($value, 'required')?

Tags: codeigniter-4

Api postdata:

```
{
"username": "abc@gmail.com",
   "password" : 12345678,
}
```

Controller code:

```
 $validation =  \Config\Services::validation();
$validation->setRules([
                                'username' => 'required',
                                'password' => 'required'

                        ]);
```

the above code snippets does not work.it gives error like username is required and password is required.

Answer (score 0):

The format you are posting looks like a json array/object. If it is, make sure you are converting it first with json_decode before passing it to validation.